# I need help with the proof of Theorem 4, Chapter I in E. Landau's "Foundations of Analysis"

Tags: natural-numbers, peano-axioms

I need help with the proof of Theorem 4, Chapter I in E. Landau's "Foundations of Analysis"

> To every pair of natural numbers $x$, $y$, we may assign in exactly one way a natural number, called $x+y$ such that:
>
> 1. $x+1=x'$ [where $x'$ has to be interpreted as the successor of $x$] and
> 2. $x+y'=(x+y)'$ for every $x$ and every $y$.

Now, he goes on:

> First we will show that for each fixed $x$ there is at most one possibility of defining $x+y$ for all $y$ in such a way that: 1) and 2).

Here's the crucial passage I don't understand:

> Let $a_y$ and $b_y$ be defined for all $y$ such that: $a_1$ and $b_1$ equal $x'$ and $a_{y'}$ equals $(a_y)'$ and $b_{y'}$ equals $(b_y)'$ for every $y$.

The problem to me is: who are $a_y$ and $b_y$ and either $a_1$ and $b_1$?

Comment: You could at the very least type out the statement of the theorem and tell us your difficulties.

Comment: And please first try for yourself and tell us where you get stuck etc. [ask]

Comment: Thank you for your interest misters; here's the theorem: "To every pair of natural numbers x, y, we may assign in exactly one way a natural number, called x+y such that: 1) x+1=x' [where x' has to be intended as the successor of x] and 2) x+y'=(x+y)' for every x and every y".        Now, he goes on A) First we will show that for each fixed x there is at most one possibility of defining x+y for all y in such a way that: 1) and 2). Here the crucial passage I don't understand: "Let a[subscript]y and b[subscript]y be defined for all y such that: a[subscript]1 and b[subscript]1 equals x'....

Comment: ...(it continues) and a[subscripy]y' equals (a[subscript]y)' and b[subscript]y' equals (b[subscript]y)' for every y." The problem to me is: who are a[subscript]y and b[subscript]y and either a[subscript]1 and b[subscript]1?

Comment: I tried to format your transcription and included it in the main body of the question. Please check whether I introduced any mistakes.

Comment: WOW! So kind of you Martin! Thank you VERY much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Landau wants to prove that there is only one binary function $+$ with the stated properties. This is equivalent to saying that for every fixed $x$, there is only one way to define a unary function that maps any number $y$ to a number $x+y$ and that satisfies the stated properties. (Note that given that $x$ is fixed, a function that maps every $y$ to some $x+y$ is unary and not binary.)

In order to prove this, Landau fixes $x$, considers two unary functions satisfying the stated properties, and then proves that they must be identical. In order to distinguish the two unary functions during the proof of their identity, he calls them $a_y$ and $b_y$.

The only statement that was correct in Federica's response is that $a_1$ and $b_1$ are simply $a_y$ and $b_y$ evaluated at $y=1$.

Comment: What branch of mathematics does introduce these *unary/binary* definitions? It seems that it is more fundamental and would help in studying *the book of Landau*.

Answer (score 1):

$a_1$ and $b_1$ are simply $a_y$ and $b_y$ evaluated at $y=1$. Since he's going to prove unicity of $y$ fixed $x$, such that $x+y$ satisfies $1)$ and $2)$, he supposes there are two such "y" and then proves they are actually the same. In order to distinguish one from the other, he calls them with $a$ and $b$. In order to recall they are both "candidates" to be "y", he puts a subscript $y$.

Comment: To Federica - I've been experiencing the joy of understanding in the last minutes, trying to figure out a way to convert it in a readable format but...since I could spend all the day doing it, I will simply say the biggest ever thank you (I might be stupid, or focusing-disabled, but it's been a couple of days since I got stuck over here)

Answer (score -1):

I am an Japanese almost 60 years old. I have been confused at the same place as you. I feel $a_y$ and $b_{y}$ are an expansion of $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$. The $x$ is fixed but $y$ can be any natural number so $2$ natural number $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ shall be series. So author introduced $2$ series $a_y$ and $b_y$.

I thought your question is why $a_y$ and $b_{y}$ introduced on this definition and proof.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! This short guide to MathJax (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and the edits in your post should get you going.